# Why does String does not work correctly in following code?

Tags: java, string

I need 567 in my output when i called accelerate function but I am not able to get the same. Instead of getting 567, "567 Nat" is the output which I am not able to understand. So, can anyone helps in finding the problem in this code.

```
class New {
static void check(String m) {
    int flag = 0;
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;
    char ch[] = m.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < m.length(); i++) {
        if (ch[i] == 32) {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        } else end = i;
    }
    if (flag == 1) {
        String s = new String(ch, start, end + 1);
        System.out.println(s);
        accelerate(m, s, end + 1);
    }
}

static void accelerate(String m, String s, int k) {
    char ch[] = m.toCharArray();
    char ch1[] = s.toCharArray();
    int flag = 0;
    int start = k;
    int end = k;
    System.out.println(k);
    for (int i = k + 1; i < ch.length; i++) {
        if (ch[i] == 32) {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        } else {
            end++;
            System.out.println(ch[i]);
        }
    }
    if (flag == 1) {
        System.out.println(ch);
        System.out.println(start);
        System.out.println(end);
        String s1 = new String(ch, start, end + 1);
        System.out.println(s1);
        //accelerate(m,s1,end+1);
    }
}

public static void main(String... s) {
    String k = "India 567 Nation. I LoVe India";
    check(k);
}
```

}

Comment: Ooo, please indent so it's legible.

Comment: should be `String s=new String (ch,start,i);` ?

Comment: whats the problem with end+1?/

Comment: From String javadoc: bytes - The bytes to be decoded into characters
offset - The index of the first byte to decode
length - The number of bytes to decode

Comment: if you're in Eclipse you can indent all by highlighting all and pressing ctrl + i

Comment: any reason you can t just use `k.split(" ");`

Comment: Please read [this JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) and then think about why  your `end+1` doesn't work here as the third method argument.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood String constructor with that parameter .From [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29)

```
public String(byte[] bytes,
      int offset,
      int length)
```

> Allocates a new String that contains characters from a subarray of the
>   character array argument. The offset argument is the index of the
>   first character of the subarray and the count argument specifies the
>   length of the subarray. The contents of the subarray are copied;
>   subsequent modification of the character array does not affect the
>   newly created string.

**The offset is number of charactes to skip and it is not the index from character array to start .**

```
0 1 2 3 4    //array
1 2 3 4 5    //offset skip character starts with one
I n d i a
```

So this is why the string prints space in first place

**The length is the number of characters to display starting from offset and not the end index from character array.**

So what are you doing is

```
new String(ch,5,9)   //starting from space to the i
```

instead you should do

```
new String(ch,6,3) //leaving "India " and getting next 3 characters i.e. 567
```

#### DEMO